# Parse address to string in smartPy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

Can we parse a varialble of type sp.TAddress to sp.TString like this:

> strAddress = sp.string(sp.address("tz1-add")) or strAddress = str(sp.address("tz1-add"))?

Smart Contract Example:

```
import smartpy as sp

class SmartContract(sp.Contract):
    def init(self):
        self.init(fromAddress = "")

    @sp.entry_point
    def transferEvent(self, params):
        self.data.fromAddress = sp.string(params.fromAddress)

if "templates" not in name:
    @sp.add_test(name = "Smart Contract")
    def test():

        c1 = SmartContract()

        scenario = sp.test_scenario()
        scenario += c1

        scenario.h1("Smart Contract")
        scenario += c1.transferEvent(strAddress = sp.address("tz1MFYTrMMhh7QBq8NRP6QMU2gcrcGhjSTrv"))


        scenario.verify(c1.data.fromAddress == "tz1MFYTrMMhh7QBq8NRP6QMU2gcrcGhjSTrv")
```

As Error I get:

> Error: Error in Scenario 
>   Literal format error: (string(attr(params 8)fromAddress 9)) 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Addresses are not convertible to strings in Michelson (short of really cheating with internals).

That being said, the error message could be a bit more explicit.

Also, what is your use case?
The general understanding is that this operation is useless.

Comment: So, I want to call a method of a smart contract A from a smart contract B where the method accepts a string. The smart contract B, the caller, passes an address as param to the method called in smart contract A.

Comment: Understood. You cannot do this (without using super weird hacks that you really don't want to hear about).

Comment: Haha ok, I resolved it differently.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but in this case i'm trying to assemble TZIP-021 metadata from an off-chain view. i need a way of populating the `minter` and `creators` fields with strings of the artist and minter addresses. any suggestions?

Comment: @FFF would you mind elaborating on the hacks to get it working? i have a requirement to do this inside a unit test (not inside a contract) and this would be very useful to know

Comment: Within which kind of tests? To cheat, you can first pack so that you get a bytes representation (with a prefix). You can then extract bytes, etc. This is both very complex and kind of ugly.