# Conversion of address to bytes

Tags: smartpy

I converted contract address to bytes using pack ,
and the result is this
050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900
pasting this on online byte to string tool shows an error Invalid UTF-8 detected,
How to convert this to string ?
How to find out which one is the prefix and which one is the actual data ?
Any idea on this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Michelson string are ASCII, you cannot PACK / UNPACK UTF-8 strings
No event in Japanese or fancy emoji :)

Comment: 050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900 
so what is this ? 
It seems like a hex but it shows error when I try to convert it to string .

Answer (score 1):

There is no michelson function to convert an address to a string in a smart contract.

Sure `050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900` is hexa but not a string.

- The first byte `05` means it is a micheline expression.
- The second byte `0a` means it is an address.
- The 4 next bytes are the length of the data `00000016`, so 22 bytes.
- And then The next 22 bytes `014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900` are the data encoding of the address `KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV`

You can only unpack to an address.

`KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV` as a string would be `0501000000244b543146526f467844686e4b5847506767656a4850416e4d7332376a3672635666777a56`

- The first byte `05` means it is a micheline expression.
- The second byte `01` means it is a string.
- The 4 next bytes are the length of the data `00000024`, so 36 bytes.
- And then The next 36 bytes `4b543146526f467844686e4b5847506767656a4850416e4d7332376a3672635666777a56` is the hexa of the string `KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV`

Comment: Is there a way I can convert the data part of address i.e. 22bytes into normal UTF-8 string ?

Comment: Also why is the pack function in encoding string and address behave in different way , 
Strings once packed and then converting that packed bytes to strings works as expected , but why does it not work as expected in address data type. 

What I mean is  decoding 0x 4b543146526f467844686e4b5847506767656a4850416e4d7332376a3672635666777a56 gives KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV

but decoding the data of address gives i.e 0x014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900 gives error . 

How is address data type encoded or what are they encoded into ?

Comment: It uses far less bytes to encode addresses this way, that's the reason.

Comment: Note that you would not have to read an address as a string inside a smart contract, you are likely trying to do something unsafe ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert back using [sp.unpack](https://smartpy.dev/docs/advanced/pack_and_unpack#unpacking-data). For your address you can do `sp.unpack(sp.bytes("0x050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900"), sp.TAddress)`.

Comment: I need to convert this to 
050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900
address as string , 
"KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV"

By using unpack I was able to take it on address data type , but I want it on string. 
Can you help ?

Comment: I just need to show it as a string , "KT1FRoFxDhnKXGPggejHPAnMs27j6rcVfwzV"

Comment: You cannot convert an address to a string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python example of decoding a packed address using code taken from PyTezos https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/blob/master/src/pytezos/michelson/forge.py#L180

```
import base58

def tb(l):
    return b''.join(map(lambda x: x.to_bytes(1, 'big'), l))

base58_encodings = [
    #    Encoded   |               Decoded             |
    # prefix | len | prefix                      | len | Data type
    (b"B", 51, tb([1, 52]), 32, "block hash"),
    (b"o", 51, tb([5, 116]), 32, "operation hash"),
    (b"Lo", 52, tb([133, 233]), 32, "operation list hash"),
    (b"LLo", 53, tb([29, 159, 109]), 32, "operation list list hash"),
    (b"P", 51, tb([2, 170]), 32, "protocol hash"),
    (b"Co", 52, tb([79, 199]), 32, "context hash"),
    (b"tz1", 36, tb([6, 161, 159]), 20, "ed25519 public key hash"),
    (b"tz2", 36, tb([6, 161, 161]), 20, "secp256k1 public key hash"),
    (b"tz3", 36, tb([6, 161, 164]), 20, "p256 public key hash"),
    (b"tz4", 36, tb([6, 161, 16]), 20, "BLS-MinPk"),
    (b"KT1", 36, tb([2, 90, 121]), 20, "originated address"),
    (b"txr1", 37, tb([1, 128, 120, 31]), 20, "tx_rollup_l2_address"),
    (b"sr1", 36, tb([6, 124, 117]), 20, "address prefix for originated smart rollup"),
    (b"id", 30, tb([153, 103]), 16, "cryptobox public key hash"),
    (b'expr', 54, tb([13, 44, 64, 27]), 32, u'script expression'),
    (b"edsk", 54, tb([13, 15, 58, 7]), 32, "ed25519 seed"),
    (b"edpk", 54, tb([13, 15, 37, 217]), 32, "ed25519 public key"),
    (b"spsk", 54, tb([17, 162, 224, 201]), 32, "secp256k1 secret key"),
    (b"p2sk", 54, tb([16, 81, 238, 189]), 32, "p256 secret key"),
    (b"edesk", 88, tb([7, 90, 60, 179, 41]), 56, "ed25519 encrypted seed"),
    (b"spesk", 88, tb([9, 237, 241, 174, 150]), 56, "secp256k1 encrypted secret key"),
    (b"p2esk", 88, tb([9, 48, 57, 115, 171]), 56, "p256_encrypted_secret_key"),
    (b"sppk", 55, tb([3, 254, 226, 86]), 33, "secp256k1 public key"),
    (b"p2pk", 55, tb([3, 178, 139, 127]), 33, "p256 public key"),
    (b"SSp", 53, tb([38, 248, 136]), 33, "secp256k1 scalar"),
    (b"GSp", 53, tb([5, 92, 0]), 33, "secp256k1 element"),
    (b"edsk", 98, tb([43, 246, 78, 7]), 64, "ed25519 secret key"),
    (b"edsig", 99, tb([9, 245, 205, 134, 18]), 64, "ed25519 signature"),
    (b"spsig", 99, tb([13, 115, 101, 19, 63]), 64, "secp256k1 signature"),
    (b"p2sig", 98, tb([54, 240, 44, 52]), 64, "p256 signature"),
    (b"sig", 96, tb([4, 130, 43]), 64, "generic signature"),
    (b'Net', 15, tb([87, 82, 0]), 4, "chain id"),
    (b'nce', 53, tb([69, 220, 169]), 32, 'seed nonce hash'),
    (b'btz1', 37, tb([1, 2, 49, 223]), 20, 'blinded public key hash'),
    (b'vh', 52, tb([1, 106, 242]), 32, 'block_payload_hash'),
]

def base58_encode(v: bytes, prefix: bytes) -> bytes:
    """Encode data using Base58 with checksum and add an according binary prefix in the end.

    :param v: Array of bytes
    :param prefix: Human-readable prefix (use b'') e.g. b'tz', b'KT', etc
    :returns: bytes (use string.decode())
    """
    try:
        encoding = next(encoding for encoding in base58_encodings if len(v) == encoding[3] and prefix == encoding[0])
    except StopIteration as e:
        raise ValueError('Invalid encoding, prefix or length mismatch.') from e
    return base58.b58encode_check(encoding[2] + v)

def unforge_address(data: bytes) -> str:
    """Decode address or key_hash from bytes.

    :param data: encoded address or key_hash
    :returns: base58 encoded address
    """
    tz_prefixes = {
        b'\x00\x00': b'tz1',
        b'\x00\x01': b'tz2',
        b'\x00\x02': b'tz3',
        b'\x00\x03': b'tz4',
    }

    for bin_prefix, tz_prefix in tz_prefixes.items():
        if data.startswith(bin_prefix):
            return base58_encode(data[2:], tz_prefix).decode()

    if data.startswith(b'\x01') and data.endswith(b'\x00'):
        return base58_encode(data[1:-1], b'KT1').decode()
    elif data.startswith(b'\x02') and data.endswith(b'\x00'):
        return base58_encode(data[1:-1], b'txr1').decode()
    elif data.startswith(b'\x03') and data.endswith(b'\x00'):
        return base58_encode(data[1:-1], b'sr1').decode()
    else:
        return base58_encode(data[1:], tz_prefixes[b'\x00' + data[:1]]).decode()



def hex_to_utf8_address(hex_str: str) -> str:
    return unforge_address(bytes.fromhex(hex_str[12:]))


print(hex_to_utf8_address("050a00000016014b168ccb96310249aade4ce010e4e2ec8dd4602900"))
```

Comment: Can you also share for string to address ?